# Reverse Proxy and the Reponse

Tags: reverse-proxy

So I researched what a reverse proxy does, but I'm confused as to how embedded links within the response get handled, or if the reverse proxy does anything with them.

I'm planning to use a reverse proxy to allow some limited access to our existing report server, but it's doesn't know anything about the proxy.  When a request comes into the reverse/inbound proxy, it get directed to the report server and the first page is retrieved correctly.  The response stream however has links that point directly to the report server, and not the proxy server. When the client recieves these links, the URL is incorrect.

Should the reverse proxy update these links on the way out? Do I have to confugure the report server to create the embedded links properly?  Public DNS entries to round the exposed report server back the proxy?

In all the reading that I've done, nothing seems to mention the response!

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter the URLs in the report to refer to the proxy, not the report server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- depending on how your proxy is setup, you need to create 'rules' that REWRITE the links in the response.

Configuring Rules for Response Writing:  http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing